# Chart.js 2.7: How to remove bar with value is 0 on the grouped bars?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I'm trying to remove the bar with value is 0 on grouped bar chart bars, but even though I see this solution many places it doesn't work for me.

[What I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGJa3.png)

I created this [codepen](https://codepen.io/Hoale/pen/bxamKa). It contains a ChartJS grouped bar chart:

```
Vue.component('bar-chart', {
  extends: VueChartJs.Bar,
  mounted () {
    this.renderChart({
      labels: [1500,1600,1700,1750,1800,1850,1900],
      datasets: [{ 
        data: [168,17,0,190,0,276,108],
        label: "Europe",
        backgroundColor: "#3cba9f",
        fill: false
      }, { 
        data: [0,202,0,161,0,38,0],
        label: "Asian",
        backgroundColor: "#n8c9b2",
        fill: false
      },{ 
        data: [0,202,0,161,224,38,0],
        label: "Latin America",
        backgroundColor: "#e8c3b9",
        fill: false
      }, { 
        data: [260,43,80,82,0,26,82],
        label: "North America",
        backgroundColor: "#c45850",
        fill: false
      }]
    },
    {
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          categoryPercentage: 0.8,
          barPercentage: 0.9
        }],
        yAxes: [{
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true
          },
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true // minimum value will be 0.
          }
        }]
      }
    })
  }
})

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '.app'
})
```

Any idea on how to achieve the wanted behaviour?

Comment: is it possible to filter out 0s before passing in data to chart?

Comment: I do not think so. because labels have 7 value so each dataset should also have 7 value corresponding with an index of labels. If using the filter, the chart will be wrong.

Comment: yess... i think the only solution i know is if you could change the value in option, something that only show value if the value is not 0,, something like: `function(value, index) {
   if (value !== 0) return value + '%';`

Comment: Yes. This is what I looking for, but I have no idea how to do that!

Comment: I also have this problem please let me know how you resolved it.

Comment: I have the exact same issue, You managed to solve it?

Comment: option skipNull is added in chartjs version 3  which removes blank spaces